# android:intent to view map

Tags: android, android-intent, dictionary

I try show certain longtitude and latitude I have from phone cache

```
myLocation = loc.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

However, when I call `viewmap(myLocation)`, it crashes...

```
 public void viewMap(Location loc){
    String uri = "geo:" + loc.getLatitude()+"," + loc.getLongitude() +
                 "?q=" + loc.getLatitude()+"," + loc.getLongitude() +
                 "(7 Dash)";

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
    intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"));
startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 public void viewMap(Location loc){
String uri = "geo:" + loc.getLatitude()+"," + loc.getLongitude() +
             "?q=" + loc.getLatitude()+"," + loc.getLongitude() +
             "(7 Dash)";

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
}
```